# Invalid Characters not displaying

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding, htmlspecialchars

I have an xml feed which i cannot edit, its remote.

Now when i import it to db

it says this:

```
A taste of Turkey for £21 10 Meze dishes, bread and drinks for two at Cirrik Fulham
```

but is outputting this:

```
A taste of Turkey for Â£21 Â–10 Meze dishes, bread and drinks for two at Cirrik Fulham
```

Is there a php function i can use to fix this tried `htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlentities()` no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
echo mb_convert_encoding($string_from_db, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Thanks works brilliently will accept in 9 mins stack overflow wont let me :)

Comment: This works, but if you're going to need to do this frequently, you may be better off changing the default encoding of your web server to UTF-8 rather than converting each string.